# scrollbox scrolling works but it return on beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, scroll

im trying include scrollbox, it seems working but when it scroll, it returns on beginning and it never scroll, well just look at my website.

JS :

```
$('#scroller').scrollbox({
direction: 'h',
switchItems: 4,
distance: 670
});
```

CSS :

```
#scroller {
margin:0;
padding:0;  
}

.scroll-img {
width: 530px;
height: 142px;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 0;
}
.scroll-img ul {
width: 3000px;
height: 600px;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}
.scroll-img ul li {
display: inline-block;
line-height:20px;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}
```

[DEMO of scrollbox - Example 4](http://wmh.github.io/jquery-scrollbox/)

[my web](http://artstaragency.sk/index.html#beauty)

Answer (score 0):

if you change paddings to auto?

if I open sourcecode of your site highlight to me this wrong line

```
<img src="images/circles/beauty/thumbs/januarw.png"></</a></li>
```